# React Native - why is so few apps in AppStore?

Tags: react-native

I am learning React Native and considering developing IOS apps for my clients in it. I'd like to see some sample apps in AppStore, but there is just one. Why is that?

I see so much hype about this technology, but it looks like almost nobody uses it. Or is there any other reason for it? I'm already working with React and would like to add React Native to my skills, but don't know, if it's worth it. There are some interesting tutorials on the web, but no real samples in AppStore.

Comment: How would you find out if apps used React? How would you specifically search for apps that use React?

Comment: 1. How do you know there aren't many React Native apps in the App Store? There could be thousands but you'd never know except by poking around in their packages. 2. React Native has been available for fewer than two months. Sure, some apps are written in two months, but many take much, much more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is already an app in the app store according to this [blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/04/17/react-native-v0.4.html).
And as far as I know two of facebook's apps have been built using react-native (maybe not completely ): [Groups](http://www.facebookgroups.com/#) and [Paper](https://www.facebook.com/paper).

So if you have any concerns, whether react-native is production ready: I think if Facebook can use it in their production apps it's probably good enough for you too ... ( no offense ) :D

Comment: From what I understand, Paper was not build in React Native. http://www.quora.com/Can-I-build-apps-like-Facebook-Paper-with-React-Native

Comment: Shameless plug, but I have an app live at the moment, in case you are curious https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dramsclub-whisky-reviews/id1061410137

Answer (score 0):

People are still bootstrapping their knowledge and building applications.

Also, the technology is still in its infancy.